# Failing to build a simple hello world apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am running Windows 8.1 trying to start `cocos2d-x`. I've got version 3.4 on the system and every time I try building the hello world app the following shows up:

> No rule to make target d:/android-ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c', needed by obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cpufeatures/cpu-features.o`
>
> Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   StaticLibrary  : libcocos2dandroid.a
>   make: Leaving directory C:/android/cocos2d-x-3.4/NEW_PROJECTS_DIR/MyGame/proj.android
>   Ndk build failed
>   C:\android\cocos2d-x-3.4\NEW_PROJECTS_DIR\MyGame>`

I am using the ndk r9 for this and it's located at `c:/android/adt/ndk`.

I've tried ndk r10d as well but it brings up the following error instead:

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so] Error 1
>   make: Leaving directory `C:/android/cocos2d-x-3.4/tutorialV3CPPWindows/proj.andr
>   oid'
>   Ndk build failed

But I think that the problem is with the ndk. I am quite new to this and have been using tutorials and guides, so detail would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse,check your NDK_ROOT path
the error info

```
No rule to make target d:/android-ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c'
```

but your ndk r9 is at`c:/android/adt/ndk`

They are not the same.

Comment: I've checked my ndk_root settings in eclipse it's pointing to the correct location C:/android-ndk I've tried using cocos2d-x 3.5 and its now bringing a different error as follows:

Comment: arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dx_internal_static/2d/CCAction
Manager.o] Error 1
make.exe: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dx_internal_static <= CCActionPageTurn3D.cpp
make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/android/cocos2d-x-3.5/MyGame/proj.android'
Ndk build failed!
C:\android\cocos2d-x-3.5\MyGame>